# how to create a request when an exception is caught in ASP.NET Core app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception

I would like to, upon catching an exception in my code, redirect the user to an error page of my own design. As of right now, the application eats the exception and runs anyway.

I have an `ErrorController.cs` containing:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult MyError()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

as well as an error page MyError.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "MyError";
}

<h1 class="text-danger">Error.</h1>
<h2 class="text-danger">An error occurred while processing your request.</h2>

<h3>Development Mode</h3>
<p>
    Swapping to <strong>Development</strong> environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred.
</p>
<p>
    <strong>Development environment should not be enabled in deployed applications</strong>, as it can result in sensitive information from exceptions being displayed to end users. For local debugging, development environment can be enabled by setting the <strong>ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT</strong> environment variable to <strong>Development</strong>, and restarting the application.
</p>
```

My issue involves me not being aware how to get the browser that I am using to view my app in to redirect to this error page `mysite.com/Error/MyError`

In my understanding I need to make a request to `/Error/MyError` and then the controller would open the `.cshtml` page. I need to do this in the case that I catch an exception elsewhere (not in a controller) in my program.

What is the best practice for this, or honestly, any way to do this at all?

NOTE: I am looking for a solution in the case that the exception thrown does *not* have an HTTP status code. one of the exceptions thrown is a `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`
I have seen some documentation on how to display a custom error page for specific status codes using `web.config`, but I don't think that this is going to work in this situation. (Please correct me if I am wrong)

Comment: As a side note, I am new to coding in general and would be happy to clarify anything that was not clear in this question to the best of my abilities.

Answer (score 1):

From ASP.NET docks [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-5.0#exception-handler). `Startup.cs`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}

[ApiController]
public class ErrorController : ControllerBase
{
    [Route("/error")]
    public IActionResult Error() => Problem();
}
```

Haven't tried it, but I don't see why

```
[ApiController]
public class ErrorController : ControllerBase
{
    [Route("/error")]
    public IActionResult Error() => View();
}
```

wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide the redirection in the catch of a try catch clause. i.e.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

        try
        {
            throw new Exception(); // Do something here that can throw an Exception, but I have purposely thrown an Exception here so that it jumps into the catch

            return View();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Error", "MyError");
        }
    }
```

Comment: (To other SO members - feel free to amend my answer to reflect best practices / bad use of catch general `Exception`)

Comment: in this case the exception is thrown outside of a controller entirely. I would like to know how to call a method `MyError()` from a separate file.

Comment: In what area outside of the controller is the exception showing up? In something higher up like `Startup.cs`?

Comment: yes, it is an error in the startup.cs file